# How do I get the intended post type of a revision post?

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, api, revisions, headless

I have a headless Wordpress instance with multiple custom post types. The build takes a few minutes, so I'm building a way to display drafts by fetching the latest revision via an API, like so:

```
$revision = wp_get_post_revision($id);
wp_send_json($revision);
```

I retrieve the revision just fine, but the post type is set to `revision` instead of my custom post type. This causes problems, because I need the intended post type in order to build up a valid response that I can parse on the front-end.

How can I obtain the *intended* post type of a revision post?

Answer (score 1):

Post revisions have the original post as their parent, so you can get the post type by checking the post type of the revision's parent:

```
$revision  = wp_get_post_revision( $id );
$post_type = get_post_type( $revision->post_parent );
```